# Thymeleaf checkboxes with objects list from database

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm struggling with some thymeleaf problem - am trying to create form for editting existing users kept in mysql db. What I'm trying to achieve is checboxes list inside my form where I can see checked roles (according to info from DB), and optionally change them by checking/unchecking other roles.

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
<title>User edit</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form
        th:action="@{/edit/{id}/{username}/user(username=${user.username}, id=${user.id})}"
        method="post">
        <div>
            <label> User name : <input type="text" name="username"
                placeholder="username" />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label> User password : <input type="text" name="password"
                placeholder="" />
            </label>
        </div>
        <form:checkboxes items="${rolesList}" path="roles" />
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller method:

```
@GetMapping(path="/edit/{id}/{username}/user")
    public String editSpecificUser(Model model, @PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable String username ) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(id);
        List<Role> rolesList = roleRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("rolesList", rolesList);
        return "edituser";
    }
```

User class:

```
@Entity(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private int enabled;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag

```
<form:checkboxes items="${rolesList}" path="roles" />
```

is used in JSP templates, while Thymeleaf has its own tags system based on HTML (with additional tags exclusive for Thymeleaf) and does not use the JSP tags by default.

What you want to achieve can be done similarly to the code below. You have to change it so that it matches your `Role` class. I have used a simple class with name as a String object and a boolean value that corresponds to the checked role for it.

```
<ul>
    <li th:each="role : ${rolesList}">
        <label th:for="${role.name}" th:text="${role.name}">Role name</label>
        <input type="checkbox" th:id="${role.name}"
               th:name="${role.name}" th:checked="${role.active}"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the `Role` class for reference:

```
public class Role {

    private String name;
    private boolean active;

    public Role(String name, boolean active) {
        this.name = name;
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

}
```